# In ViewPager2 recreate fragment at specific index

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, android-viewpager2

I'm using ViewPager2 and with FragmentStateAdapter to retain state of fragments. I show 2 fragments in the pager when user is loggedOut but when user logins again the i want to recreate only the 2nd fragment to show another fragment in its replacement without impacting on first fragment. But when I call notifyDataSetChanged then ViewPager doesn't recreate the fragment. If I override getItemId method then createFragment method is called but still old fragment is showing. What could be the possible issue?

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (redrawFragments && position == 1) {
            redrawFragments = false;
            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Did you found a solution?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work and no proper solution was found. So, I changed the approach to tackle it differently.